# C++ character constant notation

Tags: c++

I'm seeing some character constant notation in C++ code that looks alien to me. Please educate me on this:

```
if (dc == L' '){
```

What does the L indicate?

Is it part of the standard?

Thanks,

lang2

Answer (score 12):

`L` is a literal specifier. For characters, it means `wchar_t`, so the type of `L'a'` is `wchar_t`. For strings, it means "array of `wchar_t`", so `L"hello"` is a `wchar_t[6]`. (And for integers, it means "long", so `1L` is a `long int`.)

Answer (score 5):

It's a <del>macro</del> literal specifier that transforms the character or character array to a wide character (or wide character array).

`L'a'` is the `wchar_t` equivalent of the `char` `'a'`.

If you're used to windows development, it's equivalent to `_T()` **if** `UNICODE` is defined.

Comment: Not at all. `L` is a literal specifier, like `U`.

Comment: @KerrekSB didn't know that. I'm used to using `_T` which is a macro, I assumed `L` was too.

Comment: @TCS I know, it's in the answer.